# ¿Como obligar a que una contraseña contenga cierta cantidad de letras, numeros y caracteres especiales?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Tengo que desarrollar un programa que me genere 3 tipos de contraseña: una simple, media y avanzada. Solo que en la avanzada me piden que contenga 4 letras, 4 números y obligatoriamente 2 caracteres especiales (%$#?¿). Tengo el código para que me genere aleatoriamente las contraseñas, pero no se como hacer para que obligatoriamente me ponga esos parámetros.

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

El programa lo estoy desarrollando en C#.

Este es el codigo, si estoy mal en algo agradezco sus consejos. Muchas gracias.

```
Random obj = new Random();

string caracteres = "aeiubcdfghjklmnñpqrsAEIOBCDFGHJKLMNÑPQR%$#?¿1234567890";
int longitud = caracteres.Length;
char contraseña;
int longitudcontraseña3 = 10;
string contraseña3 = "";

Console.WriteLine("TERCERA CONTRASEÑA");

for (int i = 0; i < longitudcontraseña3; i++)
{
     contraseña = caracteres[obj.Next(longitud)];
     contraseña3 += contraseña.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(contraseña3);
```

Comment: ¿Has mirado si lo puedes hacer con una expresión regular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estoy seguro de que hay alguna solución mas sencilla que la que yo te voy a dar, y si se me ocurre editaré mi respuesta para añadirla. Pero así de una manera rápida, esta es una posible respuesta.

Lo que hace este código es separar los tipos de caracteres en 3 cadenas, una para las letras, otra para los números y otra para los caracteres especiales. Entonces, se obtiene aleatoriamente por un lado que tipo obtener, y luego dentro de ese tipo un caracter aleatorio. Se controla mediante un contador para cada tipo que no se añadan más de los deseados:

```
string letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string numeros = "1234567890";
string caracteres = "%$#?¿";
int longitud = 10;

string password = "";

int cc=0, cn=0, ce=0;

Random r = new Random();

while (password.Length<10)
{
    switch (r.Next(0, 3))
    {
        case 0:
            if (cc < 4)
            {
                char c = letras[r.Next(letras.Length)];
                cc++;
                password += c;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (cn < 4)
            {
                char n = numeros[r.Next(numeros.Length)];
                cn++;
                password += n;
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            if (ce < 2)
            {
                char e = caracteres[r.Next(caracteres.Length)];
                ce++;
                password += e;
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

**Edit**

Otra opción es tener como en tu ejemplo todos los caracteres juntos, y al obtener uno al azar comprobar de que tipo es. En este caso, tenemos tambien un contador para cada tipo inicializado con el numero de caracteres de ese tipo deseados:

```
string caracteres = "aeiubcdfghjklmnñpqrsAEIOBCDFGHJKLMNÑPQR%$#?¿1234567890";
int longitud = 10;
string password = "";
int cc = 4, cn = 4, ce = 2;
Random r = new Random();

while (password.Length<longitud)
{
    char c = caracteres[r.Next(caracteres.Length)];
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        if (cc>0)
        {
            password += c.ToString();
            cc--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            if (cn > 0)
            {
                password += c.ToString();
                cn--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ce > 0)
            {
                password += c.ToString();
                ce--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Otra opción, gracias a @PabloLozano. En este caso, se obtienen de cada tipo exactamente los caracteres que necesitas, y posteriormente se "barajan" para que de una contraseña totalmente aleatoria. Esta solución es más eficiente, ya que son menos iteraciones las necesarias para obtener la contraseña:

```
string letras = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string numeros = "1234567890";
string caracteres = "%$#?¿";
int cc = 4, cn = 4, ce = 2;
Random r = new Random();
string password = "";

for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++)
{
    char c = letras[r.Next(letras.Length)];
    password += c.ToString();
}

for (int i = 0; i < cn; i++)
{
    char c = numeros[r.Next(numeros.Length)];
    password += c.ToString();
}

for (int i = 0; i < ce; i++)
{
    char c = caracteres[r.Next(caracteres.Length)];
    password += c.ToString();
}

password = new string(password.OrderBy<char, int>((item) => r.Next()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo que haría es tener por separado los distintos tipos de caracteres que tenga que tener la contraseña.

Una vez separados, con un random se elige uno de los 3 arrays y una vez elegido el array, con otro random se elige el caracter. No se si me he explicado bien, lo intento mostrar en código:

```
Random obj = new Random();
//Generamos 3 arrays con los distintos caracteres
string carNormales = "abcdefghijklmnoupqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string carNum = "0123456789";
string carEsp ="%$#?¿";
string pass=""; //Aquí vamos a guardar el pass;
int norm = 0;  //Contador de caracteres normales
int esp = 0;   //Contador de car especiales
int num = 0;   //Contador de car mayusculas

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //Ponemos hasta 10 porque es la longitud del pass
{
    int arr = obj.Next(0,3); //Generamos un valor aleatorio para ver en que array vamos a mirar

    if(arr == 0)
    {
        if(norm<4){
            pass = pass + carNormales[obj.Next(0,53)].ToString(); //Seleccionamos un caracter de este array
            norm = norm + 1;
        }
    }else if(arr == 1)
    {
        if(num<4){
            pass = pass + carNum[obj.Next(0,10)].ToString(); //Seleccionamos un caracter de este array
            num= num+ 1;
        }
    }else
    {
        if(esp<2){
            pass = pass + carEsp[obj.Next(0,5)].ToString(); //Seleccionamos un caracter de este array
            esp= esp+ 1;
        }
    }
}
```